# What physical ways can the Kármán line be used?

Tags: karman-line

I have also seen many posts on this. I understand what the line is used for [legally](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/31665/what-is-the-practical-use-of-the-karman-line). The [Kármán plane](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/29721/what-would-a-k%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n-plane-look-like-a-bird-or-a-plane) or a plane that is most efficient at the line regardless of the shape seems not to have a specific purpose but maybe I am wrong?

I left this link below as an example on how the line might be used:

[Challenging the Kármán line from above](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/challenging-karman-line-from-above)

[image]

Comment: @uhoh fix it i think you may change it.

Comment: One particular user seems to be obsessing about it, and resisting urges to take a look into an orbital mechanics book. Thus, ignorance prevails and the circle repeats itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a number of reasons human reasons like giving someone astronaut wings, winning the X prize or for rules around national boundaries there is a need for a hard divider between 'space' and 'atmosphere' and the calculations for the Karman line provide a convenient mathematical way to do that. The fact that the Karman line of 100km used for most purposes is actually some distance from the ~85km point that Karman calculated is possibly telling in terms of how meaningful the value is other than it being a round number higher than aircraft can fly and lower than space craft can sensibly sustain orbit.

So the Karman line is a legal construct for space law and administration, and almost meaningless for actual engineering.

Comment: What about for reentry?

Comment: @Muze - The only real impact to re-entry is that legally you would need airspace and traffic clearance for every nation your profile crosses below 100km, so a complication in doing space operations out of smaller nations. All other engineering for heat/drag etc needs to start well above that point and be tapered in.

Comment: but even that is a legal impact, not a physical one

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty abstract boundary, with gradual changes either side, of no practical use.

> No "line" has never[sic] found a practical use in engineering, and it has been misinterpreted by lawyers as having some physical significance it does not in fact have.

["How High the Sky?" Thomas Gangale, p. 156](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FWh9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA156)